# HowTo put Chain Elements into own Subdiretory in Wix Bootstrapper Project

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, chain

I've set the compressed element to "no", so the chained file is available for the current User which is installating the Software.

I've already searched on [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) and tried to find something in the Book they've released. But still I found no hint how to extract every element to a single Directory.

Thats my current Chain element:

```
<Chain>      
      <ExePackage Compressed ="no" SourceFile="Imports/vcredist_2008_x64.exe" InstallCommand="/q" InstallCondition="VersionNT64"/>
      <ExePackage Compressed ="no" SourceFile="Imports/vcredist_2008_x86.exe" InstallCommand="/q" />
      <ExePackage Compressed ="no" SourceFile="Imports/vcredist_2010_x64.exe" InstallCommand="/quiet" InstallCondition="VersionNT64"/>
      <ExePackage Compressed ="no" SourceFile="Imports/vcredist_2010_x86.exe" InstallCommand="/quiet" />
      <ExePackage Compressed ="no" SourceFile="Imports/vcredist_2012_x64.exe" InstallCommand="/quiet" InstallCondition="VersionNT64"/>
      <ExePackage Compressed ="no" SourceFile="Imports/vcredist_2012_x86.exe" InstallCommand="/quiet" />
      <ExePackage Compressed ="no" SourceFile="Imports/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage FullX64Bootstrapper"/>
      <ExePackage Compressed ="no" SourceFile="Imports/dotNetFx40LP_Full_x86_x64de.exe" InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage FullX64ClickOnce"/>      
</Chain>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Name attribute to specify a subdirectory.

Comment: Works fine. But You have to use a Backslahs instead of Slash. A Slash leeds to a compiler error. The error is telling you that slash or backslash is not allowed. So i haven't tried to use a slash only ;-(